# Trouble with Tutorial on Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image, tabs, controls

Trying to get the image tabs to work properly, from this tutorial.

http://livepipe.net/control/tabs

Here is my work-in-progress.

http://stonehouseministry.com/series.php

Can you guys see what I am missing?

Comment: You have to post the relevant code here, including a real question.

Answer (score 1):

You're running your script before the page finishes loading, so it can't find the element you're referring to.

Try wrapping a jquery on document load event around your script

eg

```
$(function() {
  new Control.Tabs('tabs_example',{
    hover: true
  })
});
```

Comment: Or add the code to the other document ready already on the page. (Note: you've shown a document _ready_ not a document _load_.)

Comment: good catch, i meant document ready =)